# Ios - is there a pattern or architecture for a screen with lots of text and paragraphs?

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I have a screen that is supposed to have a few large sections of text, a few buttons on different places, and headings for every section which have different styles.

I can just cut and paste the text on the screen and make it a scroll view and be done with it, but I am wondering whether there is a pattern or a good practice way of creating such a screen that is perhaps more elegant than just dumping a bunch of text right on the page.

I am working with storyboards.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: What is "lis" in your title? Perhaps remove that?

Comment: @JesseRusak I meant IOS :) I'll change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a storyboard and laying out the content is reasonable if there isn't too much there. (You can use a separate UIView and make it whatever height you want for layout purposes, then programmatically insert it into the scroll view.)

One alternative we often use for a "rich text"-like view is a UIWebView. (Though buttons in such a view are more of a pain.)